# creating a python 2 player game with functions & classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, while-loop

This is a game where player 1 gets asked questions and store all player 1 answers in a list. After player 1 finishes his/her turn, then player 2 gets to play and ask the same exact questions as player 1 and store player 2 answers in a different list.

I have player 1 in a function, problem is once player1 function is done running the program exits.

1- how do I make it so player2 gets asked the same questions as player1. Also, that once player1 function is done running that the program goes to player2 function.

2- would it be better to store my list of dict questions in a class, because I intend to increase the number of questions in the qa list, and how do I do so? Please see code below.

```
import random

qa = [{"question": 'mi', 'yes': 'si', 'no': 'bay'}, {"question": 'see', 'yes': 'boom', 'no': 'dos'}, {"question": 'do', 'yes': 'fool', 'no': 'sil'}, {"question": 're', 'yes': 'but', 'no': 'fool'}]

user1 = []
user2 = []

# this function is for bad input
def valid_input(prompt, opt1, opt2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if opt1 in response:
            break
        elif opt2 in response:
            break
        else:
            print('error, enter again')
    return response

def player1():
    cap = len(qa)
    i = 0
    print("Hello player 1")
    while i < cap:
        rand_q = random.choice(qa)
        print(rand_q["question"])
        answer1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
        if 'yes' in answer1:
            user1.append('yes')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('correct')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1

            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('wrong')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1


        elif 'no' in answer1:
            user1.append('no')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('correct')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1

            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('wrong')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1
def player2():
    cap = len(qa)
    i = 0
    print("Hello player 2")
    while i < cap:
        rand_q = random.choice(qa)
        print(rand_q["question"])
        answer1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
        if 'yes' in answer1:
            user1.append('yes')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('correct')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1

            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('wrong')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1


        elif 'no' in answer1:
            user1.append('no')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('correct')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1

            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user1.append('wrong')
                qa.remove(rand_q)
                i += 1

def play():
    player1()
    player2()
    
play()
```

since I'm new at coding I'm wondering if this the best approach for a 2 player game since I plan on growing the size of the game. Any suggestions, ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Check your indentation, loops in particular.  Also, learn to use a debugger to see just what your program is doing when it executes.

Comment: @ScottHunter as far as indentation the code runs. The bad indentation might've been while I'm writing the code on here. Copy on using a debugger.

Comment: "Code runs" isn't necessarily the same as "code runs *correctly*"

Comment: yes indeed @ScottHunter. Fixed the indentation but the problem still remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very quick refactor to make it so you don't have to copy and paste the quiz logic for each player.  Note that we don't pop the questions out of `qa` (instead we just `shuffle` the list), which makes it easier to reuse the same questions -- currently your program exits after `player1()` because that function empties the question list and leaves nothing for `player2` to do, but the below code should fix that.

(edit to reflect comments -- just shuffle once, and declare everything in `play()`)

```
def quiz(qa, user):
    for rand_q in qa:
        print(rand_q["question"])
        answer1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
        if 'yes' in answer1:
            user.append('yes')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user.append('correct')
            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user.append('wrong')
        elif 'no' in answer1:
            user.append('no')
            print(rand_q.get(answer1, ''))

            answer1_1 = valid_input("enter 'yes' or 'no'\n", "yes", "no")
            if 'yes' in answer1_1:
                user.append('correct')
            elif 'no' in answer1_1:
                user.append('wrong')

def play():
    qa = [
        {"question": 'mi', 'yes': 'si', 'no': 'bay'}, 
        {"question": 'see', 'yes': 'boom', 'no': 'dos'}, 
        {"question": 'do', 'yes': 'fool', 'no': 'sil'}, 
        {"question": 're', 'yes': 'but', 'no': 'fool'},
    ]
    user1, user2 = [], []

    random.shuffle(qa)

    print("Hello player 1")
    quiz(qa, user1)
    print("Hello player 2")
    quiz(qa, user2)
    
play()
```

Comment: makes sense that the list being emptied causes player2 not to run. But wouldn't shuffle just reorder the list and leave the potential for the same question to be asked?

Comment: No, because then we iterate through in (shuffled) order, so we're not going to get the same item twice.  Much simpler approach than popping things out, since (a) you don't have to mutate the list inside the loop and (b) you can do a simple iteration over the list instead of having to keep track of a counter.

Comment: thank you for clarifying! This is more than intended to receive. 1 more thing, would store the list of questions in a class or no?

Comment: the refactoring works but how do I get both players to be asked the same questions in the same order?

Comment: If you want them to have the same questions in the same order, remove the `shuffle` from the `quiz` function, and instead do it once before you call `player1` and `player2`.

Comment: Regarding putting all that stuff in a class: I'd actually just declare it inside the `play()` function.  I don't think putting everything in a class necessarily adds any value.

Comment: copy on the class. Don't get me wrong I do want questions to be shuffled since I don't want the game to ask the same questions in the same order everytime you play. It's just once once you're locked in the game the questions are shuffled then both players get asked same questions in the same order if that makes sense.

Comment: much appreciated. It works as it should now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As mentioned in the comments your indentation for the while loops are incorrect. It is just running the next line (`rand_q = random.choice(qa)`), and due to that the value of `i` is never incremented (as it never reaches the next lines of code), the while loop keeps running forever.</strike>

EDIT - Seems like the code was properly intended in the OP after reading the comments

I will answer the questions now updated-

1. because in the `player1` you keep removing values from the `qa` list, by the time it runs the `player2` code, the `qa` list is empty and hence the `while i < cap:` condition is never true and player2 code never runs.

   You can create a copy of `qa` list for processing in both the codes, this can be done by

   ```py
   qa_copy = list(qa)

   # OR

   qa_copy = qa.copy() # Since python 3.3
   ```

   So instead of using `qa` directly in each player function, you will create a copy first and only use that copy in the function.
2. Depends on how you want to add the questions,

   **is it to be added programmatically?**

   If so, you can use `list.append(new_question)` to add a new question

   **If the questions are static but there are a lot of them and you are worried they will make the code untidy**

   you can store these in a separate file and load the file on start of the python program.

Comment: as far as now the questions are static so I have them stored in another module and I just import them. In terms copying the questions I need both players to be asked the same questions in the same order.